# How to have a mysql database in my production environment when deployed to Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails application that I've deployed to heroku, and I don't know how to have a mysql database for the production environment. (The mysql database for local environment is already created without a problem.)

Question1:
Here are some parts of heroku config. You can see below that CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL and DATABASE_URL share the same host, but the other parts are different. Which should be included in the production part of database.yml?

```
$ heroku config
=== exampleapp Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:mysql://<username1>:<password1>@<host1>/<database1>?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:mysql2://<username2>:<password2>@<host1>/<database2>?reconnect=true
```

Here's my database.yml. (I've included the username, host and password of CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.)

```
default: &default
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: exampleapp
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
  password: xxx
  host: localhost

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: exampleapp
  username: <username1>
  host: <host1>
  password: <password1>
```

Question2:
I've run "heroku run rails db:migrate", but the tables weren't created, even though all the necessary migration files are created under db/migrate directory in my repository.
When I checked the mysql for heroku production environment (is this the right way to check it?), this is what happened;

```
$ mysql -u <username1> -p -h <host1> //username and host of CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
$ mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.18sec)
```

If I create the tables from scratch here using SQL, do they get linked to the app? (`CREATE TABLE db_name.tbl_name (col_name data_type,...)` etc.)
I have a whole set of database for local environment, so it'd be great if I can move the tables with the data inside to the production environment. Are there any ways I can do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For production systems it is best practice to pull the database information from environment variables rather than hardcoding them in `config/database.yml`. That's why the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is set in Heroku. You can just access it in `config/database.yml` like this:

```yaml
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Second, `db:migrate` runs migrations against an existing database, but it doesn't create it. If you are using a version of Rails earlier than 6.0, there are three tasks to set up a new database:

```
% heroku run rails db:create 
% heroku run rails db:schema:load 
% heroku run rails db:seed
```

The `db:create` tasks creates the database, `db:schema:load` initializes your app's tables from `db/schema.rb`, and `db:seed` seeds the database using whatever you've put in `db/seeds.rb`

Rails 6+ adds a `db:prepare` task that rolls the creation tasks into one:

```
% heroku run rails db:prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above. We shouldn't hard code database details in code As this information get updated in case of database upgrades by ClearDB. This should be pulled from environment variables. As from ENV its complete URL, We can extract details like below

```
require 'uri'
database_url = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
user_info = database_url.userinfo.split(':')

default: &default
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database_url.path[1..-1]
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user_info.first
  password: user_info.last
  host: database_url.host
```

For the second question, Can you check your schema.rb. is it having all the tables required on production

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!! I learned to write the database.yml using ENV. And my schema.rb had all the tables required. Thank you!!